# matchstr() acts differently when used in script?

Tags: vimscript, regular-expression

I have these lines in a script:

```
" go to start of file and search until the end
call cursor([1,1])
let moreLinesToGo = v:true
let b:qtags = []

while (moreLinesToGo)
  " search for lines like ":344f:", ":2:", ":234hello:"
  let lineWithTag = search('^:\d\{1,4\}\a*:$')

  if lineWithTag == 0
    let moreLinesToGo = v:false
  else
    let qtag = getbufline(bufname('.'), lineWithTag)
    " put only the numbers into b:qtags, e.g. "344", "2", "234"
    let b:qtags += [matchstr(qtag, '\d\+')]
  endif

endwhile
```

What happens that when I execute this file, ":344f:" is put into the list. However when I execute it manually (in cmdline mode), I get "344".
How can this happen? '\d+' seems to match everything??

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `getbufline(...)` returns a list of lines. In your case the list only contains one element. Then the second to last line from [`:help matchstr()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#matchstr%28%29) is important:

> When {expr} is a List then the matching item is returned.

Use `let qtag = getline(lineWithTag)` instead.

Another idea:

```
let b:myTags=map(filter(getline(1, line('$')), { idx, val -> match(val, '^:\d\{1,4\}\a*:$') >= 0 } ), { idx, val -> matchstr(val, '\d\+')})
```

- `getline(1, line('$'))` returns a list containing all lines in the file
- `filter(...)` filters the list with the given lambda
- `map(...)` maps the entries to only contain the matched digits.

Comment: @hgiesel Could you accept this answer or is additional clarification needed?